# Problems with Latex rendering

Tags: support, mathjax

The Latex-text will not be represented as formulas. 
The Latex-text will not be rendered. 
Why?
[My text](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3098358/4) begins with 2 Dollar signs and ends with 2 Dollarsigns.

Comment: I can recommend the [Sandbox thread here on Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) for experiments with $\LaTeX$ formatting.  Some users are enamoured of using `MathJax` for text in order to have color, etc. to highlight sentences, but many users consider it an abuse when this is done for long passages.  The MarkDown features for emphasis and block-quoting are preferred mechanisms.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that there were blank/empty lines in your "formula."

[I removed them](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3098358/5). Now it renders.

That said, to use MathJax in this form is not ideal. 
It is better to write the text outside the math environment, and to include only the actual formulas in dollar symbols.