# How to left align a series of equations in MSE

Tags: support, mathjax

When I use Latex, I use the command "flalign" to left align a long series of equations extending over multiple lines. However, this doesn't work when I write something in MSE. How can I left align instead?

Comment: This may be a question you have to ask to MathJax people. I suspect there is no easy way to left align equations that way, except perhaps with some dirty tricks like AMScd or matrices.

Comment: @PedroSEDOBETTER Thank you for the comment. My question was closed on the grounds that my question already has answers [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), although it doesn't...

Comment: The answer under [aligned](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5024/742) is the answer you want; simply put the alignment character at the *start* of each line of the equation, and they will be aligned on the left edge.

Comment: @Filippo I would interpret that as: "Either the answer is there, or we don't know and you should ask the MathJax people." But as pointed out above, the answer *is* there. :)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for the help, but either I don't understand what you mean or this doesn't work. I took the code from the answer you linked and interchanged the & and \\ but the equations are still aligned in the center.

Comment: The location of the `&` is where all the equations will be vertically aligned. If you use `\begin{align*}`, begin each equation with `&` and end it with `\ \ `, the equations will be vertically aligned along their start. If you mean that you want the equations to appear on the left edge of the box on the screen, that would require you to do some very strong manipulation in Mathjax which is very likely to "break" some people's display (avoid!)], or you should just use in-line displays in their own lines, and use `\displaystyle{...}` to make them render in display size.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin "If you mean that you want the equations to appear on the left edge of the box on the screen" That's precisely what I mean :) Okay, then I'll adapt to the way it is. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: @Arturo made several suggestions.  Perhaps you should work through the possible approaches using the [Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts).  If you have a more specific issue with something you want to tweak, then you might edit your Question with one or more examples to show Readers what doesn't suit you.