# Is it possible to add a save draft option before publishing an answer?

Tags: support

I find myself writing many draft before saving an answer at one location; and that is fine as long as I remain at that location.

However if I go to a different place without a USB backup option and a very limited keyboard I am at a loss to progress with an important insight namely now that $(64)^{(\frac{1}{3})}=4$ that was a stumbling block preventing progress towards the updated answer that thankfully has received great feedback already, something that I want to invest more effort in it to make the answer even more polished and complete.

I do not want to expose any incomplete draft to a public vote until it is completely polished to publish because the current feedback thankfully already is really great, and I want to only improve something that I consider is already really thankfully fantastic.

I heard that for new questions, that a draft automatically saves, but when I go from place to place I am having trouble to retrieve the auto saved draft.

Is there any way that we can get the auto draft save function for a new question to work going from place to place?

Maybe could we have the ask question button bring up the last draft question before a save?

I understood that this should work, but when ever I try it, I never have been successful.

There must be something that I am lacking in the simple steps to revive the last question draft from a different location so I am marking this as a support request.

I am hoping that I do not need a new feature tag since I understand that this new question draft save already should be working, before publishing.

But I need step-by-step instructions how to test it,
since without this help I have so far been unsuccessful.

Thank you in advance for your help and support!

Comment: Use the sandbox: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666/ .