Difficulty Presenting Tables When Going From StackEdit To MathJax
stackedit.io is very convenient for polishing long answers before pasting them into a MathSE answer box.  Among other things, this avoids MathSE sometimes being slow to render, during the editing.  However, basic stackedit.io does not permit the following syntax:
\begin{array}{| r | r | r |}
\hline                       
  N & x & y \\ \hline                       
  3 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
  4 & 7 & 8 \\ \hline
  5 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
  \hline  
\end{array}

I briefly google-researched the problem.  Apparently, if stackedit is going to work correctly here, I have to find the right markdown plug-in, and somehow use it in conjunction with stackedit.
Has anyone else done this?
If so, which plug-in did you use, and how did you facilitate (in Linux) having https://stackedit.io be aware of the plug-in.

For what it's worth, my kludgy workaround is to (temporarily) copy-paste the relevant portion of the *.md file into a MathSE answer box to verify the formatting.

Do you know about https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts ?

@GerryMyerson Thanks for the tip.  Yes, I do know about it, and I have often used that sandbox.  However, I am currently composing a self-answer question, where the answer will be very long.  Stackedit is significantly more convenient than the sandbox, for saving changes as I go.  In the sandbox, you have to re-copy the entire answer in order to save changes, while stackedit  allows you to directly export markdown.  Also, stackedit allows both simultaneous views (markdown + rendered), and toggling between full screen markdown and full screen rendered.

Why not simply add double dollars?
$$\begin{array}{| r | r | r |}
\hline                       
  N & x & y \\ \hline                       
  3 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
  4 & 7 & 8 \\ \hline
  5 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
  \hline  
\end{array}$$

As far as I can tell, such syntax works both in StackEdit and on Mathematics Stack Exchange.
$$\begin{array}{| r | r | r |}
\hline                       
  N & x & y \\ \hline                       
  3 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
  4 & 7 & 8 \\ \hline
  5 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
  \hline  
\end{array}$$

+1: Works like a charm, thanks.
